# Show drop down values of a select based on another select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for 'Projects' as below

```
Project_ID   |   Client_ID
---------------------------
    P1              C1
    P2              C1
    P3              C2
    P4              C2
    P5              C3
    P6              C3
```

I have a **select id="1"** that shows all the Client ID's.

I'm showing an another **select id="2"** to show all the projects assigned to the client ID's.

Basically i want to show **option** values for **select id="2"** based on the selected value from **select id="1"**.

Example if some one selects

```
<option value="C3">C3</option>
```

Then below should be there

```
<select id="2">
    <option value="P5">P5</option>
    <option value="P6">P6</option>
</select>
```

Im thinking Ajax is the answer but i dont know a proper way to do it.

Comment: Try ajax using JQuery easy way to do. on change event trigger a ajax call and get JSON data and generate second select box. This will be easy and quick way. There are lots of tutorial, Try on your own first. This site is not to get your code done. Try and post

Comment: @SSingh Im using Onchange and Ajax to fetch values. But the problem is i cant get dynamic values from mysql table. I can only put static. See Shakti Phartiyal's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an event listener for the onChange event of the select box.
On the change event get the value of the select box and send its value to the server using an ajax request and fetch the value you want to show in the second select box based on the first one's value and show it in the second select box.
Example Code for state selection based on country selection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-request.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="response">
                <!--Response will be inserted here-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Backend:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["country"])){
    // Capture selected country
    $country = $_POST["country"];

    // Define country and city array
    $countryArr = array(
                    "usa" => array("New Yourk", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                    "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                    "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool")
                );

    // Display city dropdown based on country name
    if($country !== 'Select'){
        echo "<label>City:</label>";
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shakti Phartiyal but in the backend i need to dynamically load the values on the array from a myqsl table. Currently you code has static text in array.

Comment: Yes I understand that. You just have to get the values of the first select box and take them to your server. Then you can generate anything in the back-end according to your needs.
Do you need help in the mySQL fetch code?

Comment: @thowzif to dynamically add data to the second select box you just need to add the response of the backend to the <option> of your second select box.
Try running the code I just answered

Comment: I cannot use while loop inside an array(). It causes error.

Comment: I did not ask you to use a while loop.
Just try the code I gave it will really help you out.
Or please explain where do you need to use the while loop.
I'll try to provide you with an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. After using your code modal is was easy. I now have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire up an event on the first select being changed and make an ajax call with the id of item of first select.
Then get contents through ajax and dynamically create options with the data you get and fill the second select box.

---

```
$(document).on('change','select#1',function(){
var id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'your-url',
    data: {'id' : id},
    success: function(data){

       //generate options dynamically
       $('select#2').html('');  
       $('select#2').html('the options you generated');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a select [changed](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event on `<select id="1">` and dynamically populate `<select id="2">` when the event triggers. It will help to also properly name your select elements so they are easy to identify.

Comment: Yes.. Thats why im asking how.

Comment: Im using onchange but does not know how to pupulate select 2 dynamically.