# java script dyanamic created select box

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu, element, onchange

I am having two drop downs. brand and sub brands. both are generated dynamically. based on brand selected value I have to populate brand 2. but I am new to java script. could some one help. On Dropdown 1 slected change event a function should be triggered and it should fill drop down 2

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var BRAND = ['HONDA', 'HERO']
var SUBBRANDHONDA = ['UNICORN','SHINE','ACTIVA']
var SUBBRANDHERO = ['SPLENDOR','PASSION']
function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var count = rowCount;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 //*** EDIT ***
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = count;
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("select");
element2.onchange=function(){
alert(element2.value);
 }
  //Append the options from the arraylist to the "select" element
for (var i = 0; i < BRAND.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = BRAND[i];
option.text = BRAND[i];
element2.appendChild(option);
}
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("select");

  //Append the options from the arraylist to the "select" element
for (var i = 0; i < SUBBRANDHONDA.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = SUBBRANDHONDA[i];
option.text = SUBBRANDHONDA[i];
element3.appendChild(option);
  }
cell2.appendChild(element2);
cell3.appendChild(element3);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE border='1' id="dataTable">
<TR>
<td>
Sno
</td>
<td>
Brand
</td>
<td>
Sub Brand
</td>
</tr>
  </TABLE>
<button onclick="addRow('dataTable')">Add Task</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524122/show-drop-down-values-of-a-select-based-on-another-select/

Comment: Check the answer to the exact same problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524122/show-drop-down-values-of-a-select-based-on-another-select/42524213#42524213

Answer (score 0):

```js
var BRAND = ['HONDA', 'HERO']
var SUBBRANDHONDA = ['UNICORN','SHINE','ACTIVA']
var SUBBRANDHERO = ['SPLENDOR','PASSION']
function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var count = rowCount;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 //*** EDIT ***
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = count;
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("select");
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("select");
element2.onchange=function(){
var arr = this.value === 'HONDA' ? SUBBRANDHONDA : SUBBRANDHERO;
element3.innerHTML = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = arr[i];
option.text = arr[i];
element3.appendChild(option);
  }
 }
  //Append the options from the arraylist to the "select" element
for (var i = 0; i < BRAND.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = BRAND[i];
option.text = BRAND[i];
element2.appendChild(option);
}

  //Append the options from the arraylist to the "select" element

cell2.appendChild(element2);
cell3.appendChild(element3);
}
```

```html
<TABLE border='1' id="dataTable">
<TR>
<td>
Sno
</td>
<td>
Brand
</td>
<td>
Sub Brand
</td>
</tr>
  </TABLE>
<button onclick="addRow('dataTable')">Add Task</button>
```

Comment: the exact answer I need :) .Thank you so much for your assistance

Comment: with this approach we can have only 2 values in Brand Drop Down? – arun 1 hour ago     
 

       
 
var arr = this.value === 'HONDA' ? SUBBRANDHONDA : SUBBRANDHERO; what if I have more than 10 in Brand and each brand has its sub brands ? with this approach we can check if "'HONDA' else SUBBRANDHONDA –

Comment: If you want to use many brands you can use switch/case or reorganize your data something like that 
{
  'HONDA': ['UNICORN','SHINE','ACTIVA'],
  'HERO': ['SPLENDOR','PASSION'],
  'OTHER_BRAND': [....]
}

and get sub brands by key

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to tackle the issue with structuring your data a wee-bit different:

### HTML

```
<select id="brand"></select>
<select id="subBrand"></select>
```

### ES5 JS syntax

```
//a simple render function that inserts values into dropdowns
function renderSelect(select, data) {
  var html = [];
  data.forEach(function(value) {
    html.push("<option name=" + value + ">" + value + "</option>");
  });

  select.innerHTML = html.join("");
}

//initialized our logic
function initSelects() {
  //our data
  var brands = {
    HONDA: ['UNICORN', 'SHINE', 'ACTIVA'],
    HERO: ['SPLENDOR', 'PASSION']
  }

  // references to the our dropdowns (currently empty)
  var brandDropdown = document.getElementById("brand");
  var subBrandDropdown = document.getElementById("subBrand");

  //rendering the initial state
  renderSelect(brandDropdown, Object.keys(brands));
  renderSelect(subBrandDropdown, brands["HONDA"]);
  
  //binding the change event, so it will get updated, once selected.
  brandDropdown.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    //getting the current selected index
    var selectedIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
    //getting the value using the index
    var selectedValue = e.target.children[selectedIndex].getAttribute("name");
    renderSelect(subBrandDropdown, brands[selectedValue]);
  });

}

initSelects();
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9p916nob/

Comment: with this approach we can have only 2 values in Brand Drop Down?

Comment: var arr = this.value === 'HONDA' ? SUBBRANDHONDA : SUBBRANDHERO;  what if I have more than 10 in Brand and each brand has its sub brands ?   with this approach we can check if "'HONDA'  else SUBBRANDHONDA

Comment: With this approach you can have an inifinite amount of data, just update your values under brands[]