# How to create dynamic dropdown select on CodeIgniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have trouble finding solution. what I want is when "kategori" select box selected, data on "sub_kategori" shown based on kategori_sub_id. I use CodeIgniter 3 and my database relationship connected by LEFT JOIN not by foreign key etc

this is my code :
Views :

```php
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Kategori Perbaikan</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="kategori_id" id="kategori" required>
            <?php foreach ($kategori as $kategori1) : ?>
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>- Pilih -</option>
                <option value="<?php echo $kategori1['id_kategori']; ?>"><?php echo $kategori1['nama_kategori']; ?></option required>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sub Kategori Perbaikan</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="sub_kategori_id" id="sub_kateg" required>
            <?php foreach ($sub_kategori as $sub_kategori1) : ?>
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>- Pilih -</option>
                <option value="<?php echo $sub_kategori1['id_sub_kategori']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_kategori1['nama_sub_kategori']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```php
public function permintaan()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tgl_permintaan', 'Tanggal Permintaan', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['judul'] = 'Si TAPERA | Sistem Informasi Permintaan Perbaikan Alat dan Sarana Prasarana';
        $data['title'] = 'Permintaan perbaikan';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user_login', ['username' => $this->session->userdata('username')])->row_array();
        $data['unit'] = $this->db->get_where('unit_kerja', ['status_unit' => 1])->result_array();
        $data['kategori'] = $this->db->get_where('kategori', ['id_kategori'])->result_array();
        $data['sub_kategori'] = $this->db->get_where('sub_kategori', ['id_sub_kategori'])->result_array();
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id_user');

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar_user', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/data/permintaan', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {


        $data = array(
            'sess_id' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
            'tgl_permintaan' => date('Y/m/d'),
            'jam_permintaan' => date('h:i:s'),
            'unit_kerja_id' => $this->input->post('unit_kerja_id', true),
            'kategori_id' => $this->input->post('kategori_id', true),
            'sub_kategori_id' => $this->input->post('sub_kategori_id', true),
            'urgas' => $this->input->post('urgas', true),
            'status_db_permintaan' => 1
        );
        $this->db->insert('db_permintaan', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Tambah data');
        redirect('user/permintaan');
    }
}
```

I've tried everything but it's not working as expected. Even my jquery isn't working.

Comment: "Even my jquery isn't working" what do you mean by not working? any error or unexpected output? where is your JS/JQuery code? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42524213/6934036) may help.

Comment: i do use jquery on below the views code, but i think it might be not relevant because its just alert the selected data

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: this command shown up : DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost/sitapera/assets/datatables/pdfmake.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: This warning in not preventing your JQuery to execute. Since you said even a simple `alert ` is not working and the only error you are getting is about the `.map` file, I guess your JS/JQeury part is not executed by the browser. maybe it's inside a `if` block, or out of the `<script>` tag

Comment: let me see if i understand, what you want i select an option from dropdown and then base on that selection next dropdown is going to select by default the right option. Like select state and them appears in next dropdown a list of zipcode for that state?